# Multiple document upload for Spring MVC with ant

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, ant, upload, document

I am looking to implement a multiple document upload tool for my already existing spring MVC project.  The tool need to be able to upload more than one at a time and needs a progress bar.  I have only been able to find examples using spring with Maven and I do not know how to implement these using ANT.  Any help or any tutorials would be brilliant.  I was looking at : http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-jquery-file-upload-multiple-dragdrop-progress/ that would be perfect but don't know how to do this in ANT.

Thanks.

Comment: Then why don't you do it with maven?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery for your client, you can use JQuery upload file http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

and for the backend use MultipartHttpServletRequest

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Ant War Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html):

```
<target name="build-war">
    <war destfile="something.war" webxml="${web.dir}/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WebContent">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
        <lib dir="libs"/>
        <classes dir="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    </war>
</target>
```

The dependencies you can download manually from the Maven repositories and place under a `libs` folder.

Then you need a server like jetty in the example, put the `war` into the `webapp` folder and start the server.

You can automate the last two steps too with a `copy` and a `java` task.